# Rscript v3.5.0rc windows does no longer support spaces in file names

Tags: r

I installed R v3.5.0 RC under Windows and find out that Rscript does now no longer support spaces in file names. For example, if a file named `say hello.R` that contains for example

```
sayHello <- function(){print("Hello")}
```

the command line

```
Rscript "say hello.R"
```

raises an error "Could not find file say!"

Actually, I had the issue with spaces in path names such as in `WinEdt 10\Exec\R\stangle.R`.

Any hint on how I could solve that would be welcome. The same `Rscript` command works fine with R v3.4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a bug in the `file()` command. This has been fixed in the R 3.5.0 patched version.

Just in case, using

```
Rscript -e "Set.setenv(R_SCRIPT_LEGACY = TRUE)" "say Hello.R"
```

works with the stable (unpatched) v3.5.0 version of R.